# bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc getting default adapter failed selenium windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium-webdriver

Chrome : Version 108.0.5359.71 (Official Build) (x86_64)
Python: 3.7
Windows 10
Selenium : Latest version
it works for win 11 as expected but when tried to open on win 10 it logs in system and when it tries to open another page it gives bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc getting default adapter [image]

Had tried steps provided by [Chrome Issues with Python Selenium on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68844683/chrome-issues-with-python-selenium-on-windows-10)

[How to solve 'Getting Default Adapter failed' error when launching Chrome and try to access a webpage using the ChromeDriver using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561112/how-to-solve-getting-default-adapter-failed-error-when-launching-chrome-and-tr)

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507597/11863448

Comment: Without doing any changes it started working on Windows 10. Did system update solved the problem any clue?